# Apache Internal Server Error after adding htaccess to the website

Tags: apache

I'm getting following error in my apache localhost server.

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Previously it worked properly.But recently enabled the Apache Proxy Module.

Comment: I think there's an issue with proxy module.So can anybody tell me how to disable/uninstall proxy module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i could solved the issue by myself.The issue was at apache configuration file.